# Command line build solution vs Visual Studio 2012 build

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build

I am in the process of creating a CI build machine. I use the command line to build our VS2012 solutions which contain many project types (wpf, forms, MFC, c# and c++).

I use the following command line:

```
call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
devenv.com SolutionName.sln /rebuild "Release|Mixed Platforms"
```

If I look at the build output, everything seems fine. Same output as when I use VS and 100% success.

However, the executable built this way has errors at run time while the same solution built with Visual Studio work perfectly.

The error occurs at the InitializeComponent of the first WPF view shown. The error message indicates an invalid version string. I noticed a difference in the generated files (xaml)

Command line build (not working): `Myview.g.cs`

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public void InitializeComponent() {
    if (_contentLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    _contentLoaded = true;
    System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/ProjectName;V3.9.1.*;component/Myview.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

    #line 1 "..\..\Myview.xaml"
    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

    #line default
    #line hidden
}
```

VS 2012 build (working): `Myview.g.cs`

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public void InitializeComponent() {
    if (_contentLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    _contentLoaded = true;
    System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/ProjectName;component/Myview.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

    #line 1 "..\..\Myview.xaml"
    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

    #line default
    #line hidden
}
```

I really don't know why and how the `V3.9.1*` appears in the generated file, but it seems to be the problem. How can I correct it? All the files generated by a .xaml have the same incorrect `V3.9.1*` when I build using the command line.

Comment: I would build with msbuild.exe........not the dev tool.  In fact, I try everything I can do NOT install Visual Studio on the build machine.

Comment: Changing building tool isn't really an answer and MSBuild brings other problems. I do not believe having Visual Studio on OUR build machine is a problem.

Comment: Installing VS on a build machine installs a ton of "hidden" dependencies.  Using msbuild forces you to think about them (how to get them and how to package them)....since they usually don't reside on a "clean" machine.  But to each his/her own.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out!

I don't know if I should have known or if it is written somewhere in the documentation, but I'm just glad I finally found the problem.

In my jenkins job, which is building the solution, there is a string parameter named ASSEMBLYVERSION. I don't know why but it seems like 'devenv' found this variable and decided to use it.

If I rename this variable, devenv won't use it and everything works fine.